# How can I update all tables from a schema, that have different columns?

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a stored procedure that every time it is called it gets all the tables inside a schema, and then uses the results to update a column on the table (the names of the tables and the columns are the same, but every table has a different name).

The first thing I did was get the list of the tables using this command:
`SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='Schema';`

but after that I haven't find a way to use that list to change the column of each table when changing only one table I use this command:

```
UPDATE Schema.table02
SET    table02 = '5'
WHERE table02='ï»¿5'
```

so what I want is to be able to call all tables on a schema then change the columns on each of these tables and save this code on a stored procedure where I can call it every time I need it

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag the RDBMS of interest.

Comment: If SQL Server then please research dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yes is MySQL, and I already know about dynamic SQL, my question was how can I use the list of the tables to edit everyone of them

Comment: You write a loop to loop through each table, and in each iteration build the update for the current table and execute it. Then the next iteration will be the next table.